# `Reviewer`, `Steward` and other badges not selectable

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

Why aren't the Reviewer or Steward badges shown or selectable as "next badge" on the user activity page? They are shown among the help-center badges.

Comment: both of those badges are higher tiered to Custodian. i would expect Reviewer to appear until you got Custodian and Steward not to appear until you got Reviewer. think of it like the Lv. in an RPG. you might aim for Lv. 20 but your not going to see the exp needed to reach it, rather the exp to the next obtainable level

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These badges are intentionally not available in the badge progress selector because they would require additional UI to select which queue you wanted to track which is simply not worth implementing at this time given that you can easily track these in each queue respectively.

Comment: Couldn't it just track the highest progress of them all (or rather: of the ones where you don't have the badge yet)?