# Ability to choose "reviewer" as next badge on profile page

Tags: feature-request, review, badges, profile-page

Basically a "fix" for [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286269/reviewer-steward-and-other-badges-not-selectable). That question is about why it is how it is, I'm suggesting to "fix" it. But because it was intentionally left out, this is not really a bug report, but a suggestion.

My suggestion: **Please allow badges like "Reviewer" to be chosen as the next badge on the profile page.**

How it would work: Instead of adding an additional UI to choose the review queue this should show the progress for, it could just track the highest progress of a badge that you don't yet have.
For example, if someone did 300 "First posts" reviews, 200 "Late answers" reviews, 100 "Suggested edits" reviews and 0 of all other reviews, then it would show a progress of 200, because for "first posts" the user already got the badge and the 200 "late answers" reviews are the most progress he has for the other "reviewer" badges. Maybe it could also display the badge title as "Reviewer (Late answers)".

Comment: I'm in general a bit reluctant to promote robo-reviewing for the badges, but making this visible in the profile might also trigger new users to visit the queues, and help moderate which could be a good thing.

Comment: That's [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149621/the-current-review-system-encourages-fake-reviews-some-people-upvote-everything?rq=1) and it's a whole other problem.